# What is the most efficient way to upload binary (BLOB) content just using sqlplus

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

My use case is to deliver and install binary files into Oracle tables.
The files are available locally on my site and must be installed at several client sites only by using sqlplus. 
I currently do this by locally using a Python script that loads the files and then generates a sql script with blocks like the following one.
The scripts are then distributed to the clients and run using sqlplus.

This method works, but has the following disavantages:

- the sql scripts can be really big if many and/or large binary files must be uploaded
- running the sql scripts can be quite slow if and/or binary files must be uploaded

I was wondering, if someone came up with a better solution or would now how to improve this?

**example.sql**

```
DECLARE
    l BLOB;
    PROCEDURE i(t IN VARCHAR2) IS BEGIN dbms_lob.append(l, utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(t))); END i;
BEGIN
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(lob_loc=>l, cache=>FALSE, dur=>dbms_lob.session);
    i('/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wgARCAIXBAADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAGwAAAwEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIDAAQFBgf/xAAZAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQIDBAX/2gAMAwEAAhADEAAAAfmNji5hqsiVRWTFLctqpFXSAvCUlCNbnY64BBlGXbZDlICAEOhscDEGz2oc95F4dEDq4+kHPRiQOwA2ADhdgGkqiOvWRVyLH0+c5T1VOWfTzGX0OAzvU5j0zIZqgDqCeuctTim3OMSTJlOhKRHpzkSkCPkBVlRLCiak8DLaN52DqnkENppSgzXyZSVYpPWTnbBRjjA4UPoTPiebAByjEI7A1RHRDWN6TVzPTztPUHP28edDHSg4htDus4g6y7VBGpC0EmsCtopzkDtNiffwY6W5MXMCXhjV5zA4GACocCA7ABwKJQW/PUrJCdkoZOo8gOmC5VLE1Uwi1UQswJ3kCjTDgxMnARsISS3OSPGyA1cRN1Nz3CNz2xEXy15LiyXROkqHXTml6QXin3rLyjsZORfY4l4n6qHCvTQlD1fIMV6jnHXzAW1DkHYY4hVyeOq8qxTEYNM1mAUClpRsDEqbYHQsSa8CFkInbyESq4TUxIvqnn0IKYTOamWY2lipk4xWR0ZMOIUOibQKty9hyrSYz6osdURkYkaIVKMHDAwYm6VNJ0KzBHJA2kAxuhO2kOSoRbkKOsxqrMy1kFloZsllJF4l08/WTWeqlOS5NMM6LIx18gBiCOqmKRbUMwGpLQbQx07nU9GXGo+NaVLMnO3fbeIJbmsC35s6mLyzpdsXlfmGwwQVXZsiUPQcdCgR18x0c87VEdMRGoBbc7CjYIqCeNSHRDoGiWAAh2c6gpK0hevm6TmGAWXDZSPldAuykXpZzp3cxEdDnJQ6Wk2VEtlqQYyqlFACBnk4ylQDOGboURkS0LzFvLK86omWkV6Bq2SWiEOs1l4KKZWRpFWehxY+kQ5GsZ5UJ9HFc0Tc5WUQRgPNkLeh5/ZYEpPWe6HHrLJI506Yqt5BAXdX5L88Hr42O3g2OgQBciBaa9FX5cRKRvDTEq7JRcSkzAwNd3KqjUiC+ShDZgzdTbErMY1GvrKnl7bOePZzSl5ehZxM+IdEllQMM6Zdi1+Qaz0TTR1RiazBZUxMqsCUmSKHQ2UhToc5B0QB0QYyUpZz7oxzbp0c+6Cc9WqcVKIPOZX0OLs4ZV6OfJ2V8/K7Swb84O2fOxUTEWM5hGxhsAMDvj1QsOnrArFUzCMGUJYBeQrK7RHWxHWFS10hV7uWpamiZc1MlYGOoazWc+7OWBuqRNalY7p5zbY22DsQY42eRTo5DZZZsdG5iimiTVoWjYxrpY6jnNXOHnrI22ADgbYLAi44rz3xz9HP1kB0zFaJMi9JMjEQdGxwM5J6qqltkjtlxNCQdQbAOGG2BscBquc46FETthBh086rhkI2OjA2NOkxmU08rxjdXP31wIdAOANsFkAarbUyLe555+kDkaIl6EtKy8AR5NNbis7mdESa9XmEt4CwtjduLo54BJmhnUDLYjqIDYgNJmxJrSJRFB1cjVGkCa/MB+jjqIDgZlCpIuINgBkILiBBRAbbA6ebBAwXnchs8J0M1HkegLGVknoxw7qhNG8aQZVmRzKVmwGnQkayJbp5bHPnoc+pQTn6ViG6Ii7A6qSNhVlC6PTw64xOotXJraIawImpqLpRCLQ1G9vinvnXmhTOuas+vOu3nn09efnZpculIgS2m7mKxpsWlol+tPMn38689XU7eOtU4DUKYUYjqoPJlCVYOzE2');
    i('FBccDHWKrmWecAZSMrKYM5Ne2ZzP2MeYSRcVDsAggGpIYoSk7MSFpkNViNSQUg9hGtEaIKq8InY3F1Ry70JrwZllbp5MYNijVmUlHqFImMeewmZYngTpJFmV0LV5DXUpQbo5eojiTagReLuZfNp0hFhSms8w6VmoXKIOnkB28LaWYuFjiRuvm9BOPm7eZY0S5ec6EKTQ2BGwwcMUnUkqKyT64jUDCudT1KHM9FSQoyzzqLqhJq11kvdyWBWnKRrpgoVUfEnNTnHTATdnKPGsi0LRMDUk4uQPQ5xanUcHTzXC3N02bc3URF8kzMTXWvNezctdK8OrnSuWk0gmpXSYKvM2JCEouCiQo6HYBSxAcDbG2wDsEjUuOgYgwwG64NrPRNRQn2cmaCtxE9HzTunucmejkW/X5rFEZQzckw4BsQYsL0KbF6Obpshd+VH5umU1qTYolOeGcULzrq5UbqXhzaFbEe/TyJIZ1guYneFjSvAotVJ7sUlDt5DBOkgrzPR4b8otodxKbTOyCyLwvE14EHXM2c9R1EZ9j2c5kstRLoOXozEa82zq1JABpMIMCvfwdCTjaSl07CHLfngpSZ0kGwvp1WYBSZclmwMdCuOmoL3chJeuQzsusBXjL0MeOqrLrl5+7hpK/bDnS3n/AEXCeWOvnUKwAQR0zCmsh687XK4PNNkx0c+dF2CnFwJrErqByhsFLwOjhrGA1QoFIkejnqSLoCk6hBxIdcSNAh0QAKrMlVljoktSOJJ2UjIWFnckd0XBxWpZz9U0LJClizZs6DutmaLjSSsotzaV2gCznqOGF4DvFwqyxRPR56549POdBwSjztUcQB0qS2xmLC3lkixKtMAtPq57noiWs50qmdjo57FmPGiBwuzAAYCqVDrxAwod3FbJx5gupOgl4sZXcWd4DOpFdcjlQr2j22curzROqqdEKyL8tSvOehRoFQkgX1fL+jTzOWNlm0cPkYAeZeRQcpQ586Dzo4s+5zzumZJvKpMMq9Y3KnUkKWIOnEOlWSCXyoDGXHGVdgdiRcjr2OSokXnNzsSbkWaJXYo9ZJV5PQ5+rpjXItKRlkUI2XDY21icyoRgFsoASKSRMSbHE32EdGLCOG7uX0086eAtyKbnJlu21nLeV5UUdCc27VOZO3lpCDLd+OtkhVJXfmx6Eo0sMMsFcVBogcuOvpTzksOvlIa/Ou2ARgX5uvkLdXNMeSk6ctBVh0ELQuQtHoIAhermvzoz1U59YxFqMcu6oC5vVPI9AC3km6xWPfyC9vNjoEwbn62Eh18hmzAYayk7TBrULjcdjsTLoVkAEGwqVWvMkhSalejnKI1iKPU56rEZp9hytPGeeDhUnSbpfo4OuuZ41SZVpazLUt+XrjnZCFlwMaK+blS3RxqU2QygqQQayyLS3STn0TFtydJzgg9DibrTg7+H1Dz4UVUFom2IofGxYiWJjvQOPU5yRogvTzWEpK6wXE7uZFTFWWrvJCEIqDSnt4cVlsWbOTaOOleXrIJbtIc7KSadB2Q2UV5hzEvDphSjpWI50MrKO7cwwVysrxDp4Ya5CV5DwYgeeOnc2Ogc+NaBC6dKTq97PN3dNZTa1iSrON08ulojzGyVG01OmKUFGssd0ISasxTSR0ziUV16F6IPx2VCzlK9UxPQ870E872uQnDfl615GZAq8xlOBiA353Gd8HmpM1awOmU6CdPn95522MQVGxBqNEdfENfENfETXGWmpM+hBSIzc5LNz0JuJHSrGxdsHYln5iOmAWMxgVS/PfnV783TTQeEgpOyxzxLBANSGNsAjA2zCnVJ4ODp5elOiWvqcLOCCs2dZbARtMs3OTpVFSmnjoWYBWKlhPFZFVNZA6m5ushPr5CnP6vHZzUlpeoczno8vITqHMQo6BYYJUjakh6cznTGhoctpQ0KdBx70OUjRLkXp1nFRLkN0uecp7TgPSF59S5ytWycNR0nInZl5G6ulPNcCKrNFtoY6OU4vibFOwdi');
    INSERT INTO BinaryResources (filename, mimeType, content) VALUES ('DOC.JPG', 'image/jpeg', l);
    dbms_lob.freetemporary(lob_loc=>l);
END;
/
```

Comment: Are the BLOB file local to you (e.g. on your desktop) or local to the database server? Are you allowed to use database directory objects or similar mechanisms (e.g. external tables)?

Comment: This is basically some kind of delivery/installation use use case. The files are read locally and installed remotely.

Comment: Can the data you deliver be installed by someone who has access to the server running the Oracle instance? Add this to the question.

Comment: What versions of the RDBMS do you support? Add this to the question.

Comment: If only you use python on your build system to create the distribution, then you should not mention that in the disadvantages.

Comment: Apart from looking at an alternative method for delivery, if you're stuck with sqlplus I would add a step to zip the binary data prior to encoding in the sqlplus script; then modify the script to unzip it before inserting it into the table. You could use APEX_ZIP which comes with recent versions of APEX, or use the ZIP_UTIL_PKG from the Alexandria PL/SQL Library.

Answer (score 0):

Your python script should make a connection to an Oracle instance. Then your python script can parse (i.e., prepare) the SQL statement text `INSERT INTO BinaryResources (filename, mimeType, content) VALUES (?, ?, ?)`.

Then you bind placeholder values to the cursor (a string, a string, a blob). You create a blob with whatever python-Oracle provider functions are provided.

Use the array insert execute method after filling an array that is at least 2-4k in size.

Comment: Please note that it is imperative that the installation can be done exclusively using sqlplus.

Comment: If you need python or any other language to generate the sqlplus script, then your true dependency is python, not sqlplus.

Comment: I generate the scripts using python and then deliver/install the binaries by exclusively using sqlplus.

Comment: @doberkofler You need to put that information in the text of the body along with your question.